# Missing dxgi.lib after compiling Unreal Engine from Source

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, unreal-engine4

Spent an entire day attemting to compile and launch Unreal Engine using the custom Nvdia caustics branch here.
https://github.com/NvRTX/UnrealEngine/tree/NvRTX_Caustics

The compile process takes a couple hours. I get no errors only a few similar warnings

> Warning       Library 'ThirdParty/Windows/DirectX/Lib/x64/dxgi.lib' was not
> resolvable to a file when used in Module 'DX11', assuming it is a
> filename and will search library paths for it. This is slow and
> dependency checking will not work for it. Please update reference to
> be fully qualified alternatively use PublicSystemLibraryPaths if you
> do intended to use this slow path to suppress this warning.

And then when trying to launch an instance of UE4 from within VisualStudio2017 I get the following error several times (which is obviously related to the warning)

> cannot open input file 'ThirdParty\Windows\DirectX\Lib\x64\dxgi.lib

Have googled for hours but cannot seem to find a solution.
Can any CPP experts help?

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Ok update in case it might help others.
I think the issue was an incorrect Visual Studio configuration. I was missing the NuGet package. After modifying my install, I ran Setup.bat once more then GenerateProjectFiles.bat.
​​​​​​​
Recompiled once more and voila!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.